# How to check if my android phone supports the use of systrace debugging?

Tags: android, emulation, usb-debugging, systrace

I have read that some phones, specifically kernels do not support the use of systrace.
It hit me when the same pc configuration that does not work on my phone works on my emulator.

So ultimately my question is: **How to check if my android phone supports the use of systrace debugging?**

***Also,*** If possible, if the phone does not support it by default, can it be enabled?

**Other relevant information:**

- Running on a rooted android phone (JellyBam 7.1 Rom)
- Android Version: 4.2.2
- If it matters I am running systrace from a windows 7 ADT (also tried command-line: Phython versions 2.0.x, 2.7.x and even 3.x)

Comment: Try it and see if it works.  Complain to the carrier / OEM if it doesn't.

Comment: from android doc you must have a device running Android 4.1 or higher.
it didnt mention any unsupported device above 4.1

Comment: @AndreyMarkov Added **Other relevant information** to question

Comment: hmm its kinda hard to check modifed rom like JellyBam or other , since they have a huge modification on core functions.the only think that i suggest is to revert one of ur problemtic phone to stock rom and check systrace. if all goes well then this rom is buggy. good luck :)

Comment: Ask the authors of "JellyBam".